# Binary enviornment variables and setenv()

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, setenv

While playing around with binary environment variables in Linux I found some strange behavior where it seems some single bytes were bad. I examined it closer and it seems that certain bytes will always be "converted" incorrectly when given to setenv(). Look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char array[256];

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    setenv("badenv", array, 1);

    system("/bin/sh");

    return 0;
}
```

I execute this program, then when I do echo $badenv > test; hexdump test I see:

```
0000000 0101 0302 0504 0706 2008 0c0b 0e0d 100f
0000010 1211 1413 1615 1817 1a19 1c1b 1e1d 201f
0000020 2221 2423 2625 2827 2a29 2c2b 2e2d 302f
0000030 3231 3433 3635 3837 3a39 3c3b 3e3d 403f
```

It seems that 0x9 is converted to 0x20, and that 0xa is converted to 0xb, among others.

Am I abusing setenv(), or maybe even I'm abusing environment variables in general? I've looked in the manpage and searched around some to see if environment variables should be able to handle binary values or not, but I'm not sure.

What is the cause of this behavior, is there any way around it, while still using environment variables?

Comment: There seems to be some silent restriction on what can go into env variable. `export a=`echo -e "\t"` yields the same thing replacing tab with space.

Comment: Since `setenv` expects a 0-terminated string (a.k.a. C-style string) as variable value, the value obviously can't be an arbitrary binary data, because it won't handle 0 bytes well. I don't know why it converts control characters like `0x9` to spaces, though. Most probably some safety measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variable is split into "words" according to the value of `$IFS`, and the "words" are joined with a single separator - in this case an ordinary space. Thus the sequence `"\x09\x0a"`, or `"\t\n",` is collapsed to one space (`'\x20'`) when interpreting the contents of `array`.

> IFS - The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command. The default value is ''space tab newline''.

You can avoid the replacement by (temporarily) changing `$IFS`.

Note, however, that

- `array[0]` has indeterminate value
- `array` is not 0-terminated

in your programme. You should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, what should I set $IFS to in order to get this behavior though? Currently $IFS is not set, I tried just declaring it with no content.

Comment: You could set `IFS=" "`, then a (nonempty) sequence of spaces is collapsed to a single space, but since there is only one space, it wouldn't be changed. But I'm pretty sure `IFS` is set, `echo -n "$IFS" | xxd` should tell you to what (probably space, tab, newline, so xxd will report `2009 0a`).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks again, that seems to make it work in my original toy-program too. The program I pasted here was just something to demonstrate the "problem" in general.